# How to add a project to svn server?

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server

I have to add a project to the SVN server repository and I would be thankful to get some links or little help on how to do that.

The URL to the SVN repository is `https://192.168.1.4:448/svn/BDRAsigViata/`.
The project is located on the desktop. The path is `/Users/name/Desktop` 
and the name of the project is *BDRAsigurariViata v1.0.zip*.

I tried to add the project this way

```
  svn import /Users/name/Desktop/BDRAsigurariViata v1.0.zip  https://192.168.1.4:448/svn/BDRAsigViata
```

But it isn't working. Am I supposed to follow other steps too, in order to be able to do that?

I get the error:

> ```
>    svn: E205000: Try 'svn help' for more info
>    svn: E205000: Too many arguments to import command
> ```

Comment: Are you trying to add a ZIP archive to a version-control repository?

Comment: If you already have a URL, you already have a project. You are asking how to import files into an existing repository.

Comment: @chitza you're right, but I'm learning right now, I didn't create a product for that company. I doubt that you have been born with all your knowledge. You don't have to be this way. Anyway, I am thankful for your advice. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**[Tedious mode ON]** Are you trying to add a ZIP archive to a *version control* repository? Apache Subversion is a
*version control* system, not a simple file storage or Dropbox! It's designed to store and manage your code. Since you use the term "project", I assume that you simply zipped your source code files and wanted to commit them as the archive. That's not how it works. **[Tedious mode OFF]**

Nevertheless, the command you need is

```
svn import "C:\Users\name\Desktop\BCRAsigurariViata v1.0.zip" "https://192.168.1.4:448/svn/BCRAsigViata/BCRAsigurariViata v1.0.zip" -m "Commit Message"
```

Since you are new to Apache Subversion and VisualSVN Server you definitely should set aside some time to read [SVNBook](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/svnbook/). These introductory topics are highly recommended for novice Apache Subversion users:

- [What Is Subversion?](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.intro.whatis.html)
- [Fundamental Concepts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.html)
- [Basic Usage](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.html)

As a Windows user, I strongly recommend you to consider [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) client (and it's [manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html) in addition to the above docs).

Comment: I'm really really thankful for your answer. I struggled a lot and now it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your command looks strange with the backslash. The first one and the one in front of the server URL looks like they don't belong. Also I believe you need to escape the spaces in your path. (but I wouldn't put the last file, you want a directory).

I would write this command:

```
svn import /Users/name/Desktop https://192.168.1.4:448/svn/BCRAsigViata
```

except you might not want to put your whole "Desktop folder".

Comment: I tried your way and the project doesn't appear on the svn server. In the terminal I get this --This line, and those below, will be ignored--

A    .


















-uu-:---F1  svn-commit.3.tmp   All L1     (Fundamental)-------------------------
Loading image...done

Comment: what do you see now on your svn server? since apparently some things where commited

Comment: There is no change made. I can see the same folder iOS and nothing else.

Comment: Sorry, I can't say much more without looking at the exact data. Did you try using a graphical client?

Comment: I didn't use one. Could you recommend one for me? :)