# add Xcode project (Xcode 9) to Subversion (SVN)

Tags: xcode, svn

So I'm trying to add my new project to our svn, but I don't have a clue how I can do it. I thought i was able to do it in Xcode but it seems that they don't support svn anymore (switched to GitHub). Is there a way to add my project in a different way and import it to Xcode? Or is there another (easier) way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. The answer of this post helped me to import my project to svn. 
 [How to add an existing folder with files to SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703280/how-to-add-a-project-to-svn-server) 
 This second post (the latest answer) helped me to clone my project back to Xcode, so I'm able to commit my changes via Xcode. 
 [How to set up SVN repository in xCode 9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357688/how-to-set-up-svn-repository-in-xcode-9-0)